# submit additional data with form in mvc jquery post

Tags: jquery, forms, asp.net-mvc-3, post

I need to save data from HTML table and other form fields when i post form.
 Here i need to post form and additional array data to action.This is code i have tried.

sample View

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Support" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Support Desired</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SupportDesired, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Support Desired", @tabindex = "4" })
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <table class="table table-condensed" id="tblselectedcontact">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 30px"></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" onclick="CloseUserRow(this)"></a></td>
            <td><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ContactId must be a number." data-val-required="The ContactId field is required." id="customer_ContactId" name="customer.ContactId" value="1" type="hidden">ABC</td>
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td>ABC</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...../*all fields goes like this*/
......
```

Script Code

```
function postform() {
    var ActivityContacts= [];
    $('#tblselectedcontact input:hidden').each(function () {
        ActivityContacts.push({
            "ContactId": $(this).val()
        });
    });
   var data = $('#frmCreate').serializeArray();
   data.push(ActivityContacts);
   console.log(ActivityContacts);
   $.post('@Url.Action("Create")', data);
}
```

**Action Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Model.Activity model)
{            
  //Create code goes here
}
```

Here in action method i get all form fields in model but there is no additional data found.

Comment: Does you model contain a property named `ActivityContacts`? in which case why not just construct your html correctly so you can just use `serialize()`. And why do you have a `.each` for only one element?

Comment: Yes it has property named ActivityContacts..and i have just added one table row for sample ,actual data is loaded dynamically so i have used each function for multiple rows.

Comment: Then for a start you have duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html. You need to show your models.

Comment: you can add additional params by using JSON in post method mapping with your MVC Action method model